# How can I retrieve id text from external JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, http

I have this code.

HTML:

```
<script>
     window.onload = minutes();
</script>
<div class="countdown">
               <p>Minutes until this timer will end</p> 
                <p id="test">210</p>
                </div>
```

External JS:

```
   function minutes() {
       var x = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
       alert(x);
    }
```

the alert will not pop up using external js. Is there a way to make this work externally?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function minutes() {
       var x = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
       alert(x);
}

window.onload = minutes();
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
   <p>Minutes until this timer will end</p> 
   <p id="test">210</p>
</div>
```

Here is a working demo. Hope it helps!